# Extension methods with reusable logic - passing Action to Func<TResponse>

Tags: c#, .net

I have several extension methods for interacting with the Google Calendar API, and these all use an `ExecuteWithRetry` function for wrapping API calls within retry logic:

```cs
private static readonly int maxAttempts = 4;
private static readonly int retryFirst = 5000;
private static readonly int retryExponent = 4;

private static async Task<TResponse> ExecuteWithRetryAsync<TResponse>(Func<Task<TResponse>> func)
{
  TResponse response = default;
  for (var attempt = 1; attempt <= maxAttempts; attempt++)
  {
    try
    {
      response = await func();
      break;
    }
    catch (Google.GoogleApiException) when (attempt < maxAttempts)
    {
      var backoff = retryFirst * (int)Math.Pow(retryExponent, attempt - 1);
      await Task.Delay(backoff);
    }
  }
  return response;
}

public static async Task<IList<Event>> FetchAllWithRetryAsync(this EventsResource.ListRequest listRequest, DateTime? after = null, DateTime? before = null)
{
  listRequest.TimeMin = after;
  listRequest.TimeMax = before;
  var pageStreamer = new PageStreamer<Event, EventsResource.ListRequest, Events, string>(
    (request, token) => request.PageToken = token,
    response => response.NextPageToken,
    response => response.Items
  );
  return await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(() => pageStreamer.FetchAllAsync(listRequest, CancellationToken.None));
}

public static async Task<TResponse> ExecuteWithRetryAsync<TResponse>(this IClientServiceRequest<TResponse> request)
  => await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(() => request.ExecuteAsync());

public static async Task ExecuteWithRetryAsync(this BatchRequest request)
  => await ExecuteWithRetryAsync(async () => { await request.ExecuteAsync(); return Task.FromResult(0); });
```

General feedback welcome.

I'm particularly uneasy about the last function. Basically `BatchRequest.ExecuteAsync()` returns a `Task` rather than a `Task<TResponse>`, so I'm using

```
async () => { await request.ExecuteAsync(); return Task.FromResult(0); }
```

for it to be accepted as a `Func<Task<TResponse>>`. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the annoying problem you have, but at least you can return 0 and not `Task.FromResult(0)`.

Comment: To make it slightly nicer you could return a constant `MyVoid` type (like unit), but I'm not sure that's better.

Comment: @Stefanod'Antonio Good point about returning 0!

Comment: You should not await a single async method in another async method. You can simply return the `Task` directly, i.e. `public static Task<TResponse> ExecuteWithRetryAsync<TResponse>(...) => ExecuteWithRetryAsync(() => request.ExecuteAsync());`